# How can you get pointer to a templated member function from a template type?

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

The following code does not compile ... any idea why? Is this illegal C++?

```
class Handler {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  void handle(T t) {}    
};

class Initializer {
 public:
  template <typename T, typename H>
  void setup(H *handler) {
    void (H::*handle)(T) = &H::handle<T>; // fails
  }
};

int main() {
  Initializer initializer;
  Handler handler;
  initializer.setup<int, Handler>(&handler);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `template`:

```
void (H::*handle)(T) = &H::template handle<T>;
```

Because the template `handle` is qualified with a dependent type. (Just like you use `typename` if a type is qualified with a dependent type.)